# Copying pvc snapshot from one kubernetes cluster to another

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pvc, persistent-volume-claims

Can someone suggest any ideas, or references that I could use to copy a pvc snapshot from one cluster to another without using any third-party like velero.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Volume snapshots](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volume-snapshots/). Volume snapshots provide Kubernetes users with a standardized way to copy a volume's contents at a particular point in time without creating an entirely new volume. This functionality enables, for example, database administrators to backup databases before performing edit or delete modifications.

```
apiVersion: snapshot.storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: VolumeSnapshot
metadata:
  name: new-snapshot-test
spec:
  volumeSnapshotClassName: csi-hostpath-snapclass
  source:
    persistentVolumeClaimName: pvc-test
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In my case I already have a snapshot in one cluster but I want to copy that snapshot into another cluster without using any plugins like velero. Both these clusters are on-premise.